# Lottery ticket probability clarification

Tags: probability

I plan to buy a lottery ticket each week until I win. If the probability that I win in any given week is **p** and each week is independent, what's the probability that I'll buy at least **k** tickets?

My think that this is a geometric random variable problem but my gut tells me that I am misinterpreting the problem.

The reason is because it's a multiple choice question and none of the answers has the geometric formula as an answer. These are the options:

$$ p^k$$

$$ p^{k -1}$$
$$ (1-p)^k$$

$$(1-p)^{k-1}$$

Is there a different way to write the geometric formula?

Comment: Yes, your think is correct. You need to just calculate $P(X\ge \mathbf{k})=\sum_{n=\mathbf{k}}^{+\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}p$

Answer (score 2):

You could try to evaluate a series, or you can notice that
$$A = \{\text{Buy $k$ or more tickets}\}\iff B =\{\text{Fail $(k-1)$ times}\}.$$
Hence
$$P(A) = P(B) = (1-p)^{k-1}.$$

---

Addendum:

If $X$ is the number of trials until success with chace $p$, then 
$X$ follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p$ on $\{1,2,3,4,\dotsc\}.$
So it has the usual pmf
$$P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p.$$
However, this problem is not asking $P(X =k)$, it asks for
$$P(X \geq k) = \sum_{n = k}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}p = (1-p)^{k-1}$$
by the logic that I used above.